# Chern number in condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, differential-geometry, topology, quantum-hall-effect

In mathematics, the Chern number is defined in terms of the [Chern class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class) of a manifold. What is the exact definition of Chern number in condensed matter physics, i.e. quantum hall system?

Comment: I think the definition is basically the same fundamentally. Do you mean how it's calculated?

Comment: There is an extremely readable exposition of the Chern number and its relation to the quantum Hall effect in this [Physics Today article](http://physics.technion.ac.il/~avron/files/pdf/phystoday.pdf)

Comment: @twistor59 : I'm not sure whether the Chern number explanation is right. Bellissard was able to identify the quantum hall conductance with an index of a fredholm operator. For references see Jingbo Xia, Geometric Invariants of the Quantum Hall Effect, Commun. Math. Phys. 119, 29-50 (1988).

Comment: @jjcale I think that's a more sophisticated model of the quantum Hall effect than is usually treated (as the abstract says, it was a new interpretation - at that time).  The "conventional" treatment (Thoulness), which the Xia paper references, goes something like:  electron gas in 2 dimensions with periodic boundary conditions, corresponds to 2 dim parameter space T with topology S1xS1.  Then the set of all phases that the wavefunctions of the energy eigenstates can have defines a U(1) bundle over T.  The integral which defines the Chern class (integral of the curvature 2-form of a

Comment: connection) corresponds to the formula for the Hall conductivity.  The connection is defined by the Hilbert space inner product.  I only have cursory knowledge though, not enough to provide an answer.

Comment: @twistor59 : The Quantum Hall Effect can't be explained without taking Anderson localisation into account. The Hall conductance is only quantized if the fermi energy lies in a region of localized states.

Answer (score 4):

In quantum Hall effect(QAHE), Klitzing found the Hall conductivity to be integer multiples of a fundamental constant. This effect is independent of size and impurities of the system with which we deals with. Based on it, a famous scientist R. Laughlin proposed a theory describing the integer states in terms of a topological invariant. This topological invariant is known as [chern number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern-Simons_theory).

For details of the cern number,there is a wikipedia link.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Hall conductance can be expressed as σH=νe2h, where ν is filling factor. Is filling factor ν related to the Chern number C?